# Search bar only displaying 1 item

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a search bar and a sql database with 3 movies in

```
Name:Star Wars: Description: Contains the word group
Name:301: Description: Contains the word group
Name:destroyer: Description: Contains the word group
```

BUT when ever I search for the word "group"

I only get one result usually:

here is my php code:

```
 if(!isset($_POST['search']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");

}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM php_item WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0)
{

$search_rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
 }


?>


          </p>
          <p>&nbsp; Search Results</p>
          <?php

          if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) != 0){
              do{ ?>

              <p>
              <?php echo $search_rs['Name']; ?>

             <?php     }while($searchr_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));





          } else {
            echo "No Results Found";  
          }





          ?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: remove the first `$search_rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: -1. op is using a do/while loop, so that first fetch is necessary

Comment: @MarcB yes i know, thats not an issue for me atm

Comment: its because the the desciption of 301 contains the word group?

Comment: @user3586915 SQL Injection should always be an issue you're concerned with.  Even if it's for something that would never be exposed to the outside world.  Getting into the habit of using Parameterised SQL is one of the better habits to get into.

Comment: @Siyual our lecturer is doing is arse backwards, he wants us to make the wqebsite like this THEN he will teach up to parameterise our SQL

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
changed $search_rs to $searchr_rs in my old post & now it will work

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['search']))
{
    header("Location:index.php");

}

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM php_item WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'  OR Description LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' ";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);
//print_r($search_query);
if(!$search_query){
die(mysql_error());
}
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)>0)
{
 echo '<p>&nbsp; Search Results</p>';

              while($searchr_rs=mysql_fetch_array($search_query))
              {

             echo ' <p>';
              echo $searchr_rs['Name'];
    echo '</p>';
                 }





          } else {
            echo "No Results Found";  
          }




?>
```

Comment: it just made it worse haha

Comment: @user3586915 HOw ? have u tried this code? what error you get?

Comment: undefined variable: $search_rs.. BUT i added isset to the front.. im getting no errors but nothing is displaying but im not getting the no results found so it is search just not displaying

Comment: @user3586915 Use my edited answer no need to use isset at $search_rs because you have typed the name as $searchr_rs which I have updated

Comment: when i didnt add isset i was getting errors.. saying undefined variable.. therefore i added isset to get rid of them errors then i started to get results that werent showung